# How long is the slow query log time of mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I I want to record the slow query of mongo, but I don't know how long to set it. How long do you usually set it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it in [operationProfiling Options](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/#operationprofiling-options) in Configuration file or as parameter `--slowms <integer>`, see https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/program/mongod/#std-option-mongod.--slowms

Default is 100ms. Set it according to your retirements. If your application runs many big queries then the logfile may become bigger and a higher threshold could be better.